# Select last row from range selection

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

Similar to how we use range(b2:b & lastrow), how can we achieve this using Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select & Lastrow.
So I want to go to B1, control arrow down, and then control shift arrow down. Instead of using the control shift arrow down, I want to achieve the result using LastRow. Is there a way to do this, please?
Thanks

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```vb
Sub Select_last_rowrange_selection()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Range("b1").Worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    
    'this will select the column B used range
    Range("b2:b" & lastrow).Select
    
    'this will select the last row of column B
    Range("b" & lastrow).Select
End Sub


Sub Select_last_row_from_range_selection()
    Dim lastrow As Long, rng As Range
    Set rng = Selection
    lastrow = rng.Rows.Count
    'this will select the last row of selected range
    rng.Rows(lastrow).Select
End Sub
```

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    rem select only one cell
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
'        ...
    rem select more than one cells
    Else
'        ...
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Oscar, I'll try to explain a bit better, this is somewhat the right path. I have a IF statement: IF selection is one cell 'do this' Else 'do that'. So how can I differentiate when I select just one cell or multiple in column B. If I use CTRL SHIFT ARROW-DOWN, and there is just B2 with data, it selects the whole column and again classifies as multiple data. Sorry if unclear

Comment: @Ardi It's really unclear. I can only understand your sentence " I have a IF statement: IF selection is one cell 'do this' Else 'do that'. So how can I differentiate when I select just one cell or multiple in column B." Use the **Range.Cells.Count** to determine the selected cells count you got. `Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    Else
    End If
End Sub
` refer to my answer end